# Can't solve package or namespace load failed for R ‘later’

Tags: r, windows, package, rstudio

I am using Rstudio to load the package "later" running into the following error:

```
library(later)
Fehler: package or namespace load failed for ‘later’:
 .onLoad in loadNamespace() für 'later' fehlgeschlagen, Details:
  Aufruf: createCallbackRegistry(id, parent_id)
  Fehler: Can't create event loop 0 because it already exists.
```

Loading the package using the RGUI works fine. Any suggestions what is causing the problem?

Furthermore, loading the package seems to work when I wait a couple of minutes after opening Rstudio.

I do not understand what kind of event loop might already exist.

It might be noteworthy that this problem seem to occur, when I work remote.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] later_1.3.0
```

Comment: You should give details about your setup, e.g. show us the result of `sessionInfo()`, and tell us what version of `later` you are trying to load.  This information should be edited into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the message you saw if you try to run the `later:::.onLoad` function twice.  That shouldn't happen normally, but it might happen if you load it, unload it, and load it again.

Given your comment that it works if you wait a couple of minutes, I'd guess that RStudio is loading it then unloading it, but there's some delay in the full unloading.  I don't know if there's any way to affect this.

Comment: Thanks @user2554330. Even opening the RGUI and running later:::.onLoad() throws the error. Strange!

Comment: That's not strange at all.  When you load `later`, R runs that function.  It needs to load it before it can evaluate `later:::.onLoad()`, so that guarantees it to run twice.  The strange part is that it appears you're running it twice in RStudio.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Have you tried to reinstall the package? For me this worked.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35141071)