# Later Package event loop 0

Tags: r, httpuv

I am trying to use httpuv and for that the later package has to be installed, when i do library(httpuv) i get this:
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘httpuv’:
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'later', details:
call: NULL
error: Can't create event loop 0 because it already exists.

if i do library(later) i get this:

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘later’:
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'later', details:
call: NULL
error: Can't create event loop 0 because it already exists.

I need to be able to use httpuv to authenticate through AzureAuth.

Comment: Maybe try restarting R? Do you already have the package loaded? What version of the package are you using? What R version are you using? Are you using RStudio? If so, what version?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73770475/cant-solve-package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-r-later